# Spring MVC to mobile with Cordova

Tags: cordova, spring-mvc, mobile

Is it possible to create a responsive web app with Spring MVC and then convert it to mobile app with Cordova?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is YES. You can convert a spring mvc application to mobile.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713835/desigining-a-mobile-app-for-an-existing-spring-mvc-application-spring-mobile-or) is the solution you are looking for.

Refer [this](https://medium.com/code-divoire/going-mobile-wrapping-an-existing-web-application-in-cordova-phonegap-106d8b60bb9a) article for more clarity.